# Improfile working fine in interactive mode, returning NaN when non-interactive

Tags: image, matlab

I wish to obtain the linear profile across an image. The image `Img` is a 800x800 double array (some of its elements are NaN).
When I use `improfile` and define the path interactively, I get the profile I want.

when I write:

```
C=improfile(Img, [1 1], [700 700]);
```

C only contains one NaN element.

can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab indexes matrices starting with 1, not 0, so your input coordinates are not valid.

Try something like this:

```
C = improfile(Img, [1 800], [1 800]);
```

Comment: The zeros where a typo in my question, thanks for pointing it out. The problem was the definition of the coordinates. Your solution works. Coordinates have to be [x1 x2] [y1 y2] instead of [x1 y1] [x2 y2]. The code in my question tries to compute the profile between two points with the same coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that would cause a problem, too, but it should return 0 instead of NaN for the case of a zero-length profile.

Comment: In fact, it gives the value at that specific location [1 700]. In my case it was NaN.